# Switching between windows with only one instance of them(follow UP)

Tags: c#, wpf

So basically my question is EXACTLY the same as asked in the following question
[Switching between windows with only one instance of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746336/switching-between-windows-with-only-one-instance-of-them)

HOWEVER
I want my memory to be freed when I switch between windows.
If I understand correctly if you go from MainWindow to Window1 you are creating a new instance of Window1 and if you go back(to MainWindow) there is a reference so no new instance is created.But if you click the button again to go to Window1 AGAIN then it creates a new instance of Window1 thus wasting memory.
So my question is how can I free space(or use the same instance when I switch between the windows any number of times)

Apologies for using a previous already answered question(it seems like that solution doesn't completely satisfy my question or maybe I am lacking a some knowledge)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retain state then the obvious approach is to instantiate a given window the first time, stash that instance away somewhere then use it the next time.
The way I would probably do that is with a dictionary.
Use the type of the window as the key and an instance as the value.

This is based on some code I have in a sample which works with usercontrols.
Pretty much just swap window for usercontrol:

```
    private void Navigate (Type viewType)
    {
        Window win;
        if (Views.ContainsKey(viewType))
        {
            win = Views[viewType];
        }
        else
        {
            win = (UserControl)Activator.CreateInstance(viewType);
            Views[viewType] = win;
        }
        win.Show();
    }
    private Dictionary<Type, Window> Views = new Dictionary<Type, Window>();
}
```

And you'd get type of a window something like:

```
 xxxx = typeof(Window1);
```

You still want to make sure the windows are hidden rather than closed.

Comment: Hello Andy and thanks for your reply. I am going to be honest I have no idea what you did here mainly because I didn't know something like Dictionary's exist in c#(found out from you haha).Anyway I tried a bit of research and implementation and I am still stuck.Is it possible for you to maybe give me code as an example(not like you did I mean actual code involving two WPF windows and how it would work).Thank you regradless.

Comment: The code would be very similar to the sample https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmPvL3r385QhgooOmyjgYmpQeM2kVw Instead of usercontrols, use windows and show them as the code above does. Do you really particularly need multiple windows anyhow? Often a single window app ( like the sample ) is easier for users to work with.

Comment: It is more of a learning experience then a "need".I will check the code thanks a lot.